# Length and thickness of overline when using unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

Here is a wrong behavior of the package unicode-math. With the code

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\def\ooverline #1#2#3%
{\mkern#1mu \overline{\mkern-#1mu #3 \mkern-#2mu}\mkern#2mu}
\def\barB{\ooverline40{B}}

\begin{document}
$(1)$\quad                     $\barB + \barB$\par
$\scriptstyle(2)$\quad         $\barB + \barB$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle(3)$\quad   $\barB + \barB$\par
\end{document}
```

where I call only the unicode-math package (no font is defined), I get the following, where the length and the thickness of the FIRST overline is wrong in (2) and (3): 
[image: the length and the thickness of the first overline is wrong in (2) and (3)]

If I remove the package unicode-math, everything is fine:
[image: without unicode-math, everything is fine]

Comment: were the second and third lines of each group meant to decrease in size over the whole line?  if so, note that `\quad` should be recognized in math mode, so it's not necessary to interrupt it for the space.